# Displaying x,y coordinates not working correctly in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, csv, excel, display

My issue is similar to [Displaying X, Y coordinates on ArcGIS not working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172878/displaying-x-y-coordinates-on-arcgis-not-working) but the solution there did not work for me.

I am importing Excel data into ArcMap, and have already saved it as a CSV. When I Display X, Y Data... from the dropdown list, it shows the points at "0,0" on the map. When I change the projection from the WGS84 to Africa_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic, it shifts the points to center on the African continent.

When I brought the CSV into ArcMap, it converted my formatting of decimal degrees (correctly, I believe) and then I padded them with zeroes as that seemed to be other peoples problems (pictures).

The points themselves are all clustered within 1.0m of each other. Again incorrect, but there seems to be slight variation in x, y.[image: picture shows coordinate conversion done by arcmap and then the visualization of the data points]

Answer (score 1):

When you add the x,y initially keep the system in WGS84. Those are degree coordinates and if I am not mistaken Albers is a metre system. Once you have the points as a layer run the reproject tool to get them to Albers.

Comment: Are you sure you've got the X and Y the right way around? S~1, E38.35 is in Kitui, Kenya but S38.35, E~1 is in the ocean. From what I can see there's not much difference in the points so it stands to reason that they are closely clustered... where are you expecting the points to be?

Comment: It looks like the X and Y are correct. Plotting them in Google Earth it looks like they may be homesteads. My concern is where the original poster said they were 0.1m apart. It would seem that the coordinates were brought in on a metre coordinate system. Explaining the clustering of the coordinates in the center of the continent. ArcMap would be reading those coordinated as -0.98425m S and 38.34838m E. The 0,0 coordinates could be empty cells kept in the Excel document post saving as CSV and can be deleted.